# Windows Hello no longer working with my Kinect

Tags: windows-10, kinect, windows-hello

I've setup Driver Flighting to receive the beta drivers that let my Kinect support Windows Hello, but I don't get the option to enable it in Sign-in Options.

These are the instructions I followed: [Use your Xbox One Kinect to sign in with Windows Hello](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/use-your-xbox-one-kinect-sign-windows-hello); [How do I configure my PC to receive test distribution drivers?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt149093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It used to work before when I was on the fast-track builds, but those broke my Windows and I'm back on Build 10586.104.

Still, I've setup everything properly but can't get it to work.

Here's my registry:[image: Regedit setup properly]

And here's the drivers failing to update:
[image: Driver update not working]

I've enabled Developer mode in **Settings > For Developers**.

Any idea how I can get my Kinect to sign me in with my face again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to update the WDF KinectSensor Interface 0 driver to version 2.1.1512.9000 (sorry, I didn't know what the previous version was.

This was possible after Windows installed Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3140743).

Stragely this also happened:
[image: Trojan:Wind32:Varpes.J.plock!]
*Trojan:Wind32:Varpes.J.plock!*

I have no idea if any of these things are related, but I removed the trojan and all is well:[image: Windows Hello]